# how to load the data and how to do data augmentation using pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am newbie to Pytorch, I am doing Image classification problem , But I didn't understand how to load the image from load directory, please help me how to load the data image data and how to augmentation.

here my data looks like this:

```
train=pd.read_csv('dataset/train.csv')
test=pd.read_csv('dataset/test.csv') 
train.head()
Image   Class
0   image7042.jpg   Food
1   image3327.jpg   misc
2   image10335.jpg  Attire
3   image8019.jpg   Food
4   image2128.jpg   Attire
```

here my Images folder:

```
file_path='dataset/Train Images'
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use Pandas for this. Check out this tutorial on creating PyTorch dataloaders for image data: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use torchvision for this. Assuming that you have all train/test images separated into two folders called `train` and `test`, here is some example code on how to load and iterate over the images:

```
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

def load_dataset(data_path):
    dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path,
        transform=transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
    )
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset,
        batch_size=1,
        num_workers=0,
        shuffle=True
    )
    return data_loader

train_loader = load_dataset(f'{base_dir}/train')
test_loader = load_dataset(f'{base_dir}/test')

for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
   # Train model

...

for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(test_loader):
   # Evaluate model
```

You can increase the `batch_size` if you want to train your model in batches, add transformers to the `transform` argument to augment the images, and plenty of other things.

Check out the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/index.html